# HTML5 web based google play leaderboard submission issues

Tags: javascript, html, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am trying to implement a Google Play leaderboard in a very basic javascript game:

I have included what I think are the necessary meta tags, signon, and scripts in my index.html file:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
<meta name="google-signin-callback" content="signinCallback" />
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games" />
```

I've included a standard google sign on button:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

I've included the google apis:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

In my games.js file, I've included the call to submit the scores by:

```
gapi.client.load('games','v1',function(response) {

  var request2 = gapi.client.games.scores.submit(
    {leaderboardId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    score: 50}
);
request2.execute(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  // blah blah blah
});
```

But nothing ever shows up on the leaderboard. The console log spit out what I'm expecting. I've confirmed the clientID and leaderboardID.

For some reason the scores aren't actually being submitted (or if they are, they aren't being processed). Anyone with experience setting this up available for some pointerd? Note that this is not a chrome app/extension - it's a pure javascript game hosted on a web server.

Comment: I *think* it was simply a missed semi-colon on the request2.execute line. I added that and everything seems to working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Leaderboards for the Web](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted#leaderboards), [Scores.submit](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/submit#request-body) by using the URI request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/leaderboardId/scores
```

I did not see this part on your code.

Check this [firewall-defense](https://github.com/playgameservices/firewall-defense/blob/master/main.js) playgames sample for more code implementation.

Comment: I used these instructions: https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/clientsetup which say to run the POST command, use the gapi.client.games.scores.submit code (which I have included above in the games.js file) - are you suggesting just make a direct POST call from the game and bypass the gapi.client services?